# Is a mixture of real analytic functions again analytic?

Tags: cv.complex-variables, power-series, taylor-series, analytic-functions

Let $$h : \mathbb{R}^2 \to  \mathbb{R}^+.$$
Suppose that for each $x$, $h(x, y)$ is a real analytic function of $y$.
Let $\mu(dx)$ be a finite measure on $\mathbb{R}$, and for each $y$, suppose that
$$
\int_\mathbb{R} |h(x,y)| \mu(dx) < \infty.
$$
**Question:** Is $g(y) = \int_\mathbb{R} h(x,y) \mu(dx)$ analytic?

What is the most general assertion of this kind that can be proven? References?

Comment: In this generality, this won't work, you can take something like $h(x,z)=1/(z-ix)$ for $x>0$. It does hold if all $h(x,z)$ are holomorphic on a *fixed* neighborhood of $\mathbb R$, uniformly in $x$, and you have some extra regularity (such as $h$ locally bounded). The easiest proof is to use Morera and Fubini-Tonelli.